# What can you do with conditonal formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can you conditional format multiple scenarios within one cell? I've taken a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: image description]

Comment: To answer your question: "Yes you can use multiple conditions to format a single cell and have the format depend on multiple outcomes" What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can by applying multiple conditional formatting rules, but yours requires some logic applied to trigger the rule.

Assuming "Machine" and "Speed" headers are in A1 and B1, respectively:

1. Select the blank cell under Speed
2. Go to Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule
3. Select "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Enter the following Formula:
   `=OR(AND(A1="Machine 1",B1>=40),AND(A1="Machine 2",B1>=30))`

This will return true when Machine equals "Machine 1" AND the speed is greater
    than or equal to 40 OR when Machine equals "Machine 2" AND the speed
    is greater than or equal to 30 Set your desired formatting. Hit OK
    to return to the worksheet.

Repeat the above, except enter the following formula the second time around:
`=OR(AND(A1="Machine 1",B1<40),AND(A1="Machine 2",B1<30))`

This will return true when:
Machine equals "Machine 1" AND the speed is less than 40
OR when 
Machine equals "Machine 2" and the speed is less than 30

Set your desired formatting. Hit OK to return to the worksheet.

Selecting Machine 1 or Machine 2 from the drop down, and entering various values in 'Speed' should trigger the conditional formatting.